# System.NotSupportedException: 'The member jdid of type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox cannot be used as a parameter value'

Tags: c#

hi i want to creat a simple notebook by dapper in windows C#
it connected to sql
its runed good
but after i add a new item to form
it has a error
System.NotSupportedException: 'The member jdid of type System.Windows.Forms.TextBox cannot be used as a parameter value'
jdid is textbox name

namespace faradarss
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["faradarss"].ToString();

    private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            int affectedRow = connection.Execute("INSERT INTO tblfaradars (id,sen,esm,jdid) VALUES (@id ,@sen ,@esm,@jdid)", new { id=txtid.Text, sen=txtsen.Text,esm=txtesm.Text ,jdid=textBox1 });

            if (affectedRow != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ردیف ساخت");
            }
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot send a complete TextBox to sql. I guess you want its .Text property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that inserts a record and returns the new identifier where the identifier is an auto incrementing primary key.

id columns are typically a primary key that the database handles incrementing while it appears in your code you are setting the id so consider making your id column auto incrementing .

Note that Dapper handles opening and closing the connection.

```cs
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WinFormsApp1;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static string _connectionString =
        "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=InsertExamples;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text,
            LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text,
            Active = ActiveCheckBox.Checked
        };

        var statement = 
            "INSERT INTO dbo.Customer (FirstName,LastName,Active) " +
            "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Active); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            customer.Id = cn.QueryFirst<int>(statement, customer);
            MessageBox.Show($"Customer id is {customer.Id}");
        }
    }
}
// place in its own file.
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}
```